# The specified URL is already in use

Tags: azure, dns

I went to create a new WorkerRole. I used one of my URL's... I noticed I forgot to pick the Region and it defaulted to East Asia. I needed to change that but I didn't see that capability in the portal so I decided to delete the instance and start over. Now, I can't use the same URL. How and where can I purge this from the Portal / Azure?

Robert

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete the entire service, or just the deployment?  You need to delete the service to free up the DNS name.  The DNS name should be freed immediately upon deletion and there is no need to do anything else to 'purge' it from the portal.

Comment: I created the service and immediately deleted it. I did not deploy anything. The entire series of operations took about 1 minute.